# How to know the amount of requests

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm using React and Firebase, and when I check the usage on Firestore, I see a lot of request being made. The problem is that I'm not the only one using it, so I don't know if most of them are mine or not. Is there anyway (using console maybe?) to know how many request I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to track the source of reads and write happening in Firestore.  You can only see the total volume of those requests in the console.